# No provider when compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync() angular2 - 2.0 final version

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a little method that create a component using `Compiler` class `('@angular/core')` and `compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync()` method. When I create the component, have the follow error

> No provider for NameService!".

I know what is this error, but the module that I try compile has this provider:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  providers: [NameService]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Therefore, How I can inject the provider `NameService` and others providers on the component being created?

```
this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(this._createDynamicComponent())
.then(factory => {
    const compFactory = factory.componentFactories.find((x: any) => x.componentType === this.instanceComponent());
    const cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory);

    this.addToInstance(cmpRef, (cmpRef) => {
        cmpRef.destroy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours looking to code, I found that the problem is because the `Component` not have `provider:[NameService]`. I inserted the provider and all worked correctly.

I took long time to discovery this because the component was working normally, only when I tried dynamically create it, it's that the problem happened.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me hours of debugging!